# Proving that if $x\notin\overline{S}$, then $d(x,S)>0$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

I have the problem:

Let $S \subset \mathbb{R}$ be any set, and define for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ the distance between $x$ and the set $S$ by:

$$d(x,S) = \inf\{|x-s| : x \in S\}$$

I'm to prove ($\overline{S}$ being the closure of $S$):

> If $x\notin \overline{S}$, then $d(x,S) > 0$.

I can understand this from a common sense way but not sure how to prove it.

Comment: You may want to check the various characterisations of $\overline S$. Is there one about balls intersecting $S$?

Comment: "Proving topology questions" is a completely uninformative title.

Comment: Closely related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/385127/in-a-metric-x-d-prove-that-for-each-subset-a-x-in-bara-if-and-only-i

Comment: Sorry didn't know titles could have symbols as well.  Noted for future reference. Thanks for the edits.

Comment: @MathematicianInWorks Even if you want to avoid symbols, saying something like "A point outside the closure has positive distance" would describe the question much better. In general, it is advised to write descriptive titles, see also [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/10144#10144).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x\notin \overline{S}$ then there is a number $r>0$ such that the open interval $(x-r,x+r)$ doesn't intersect $S$. So any point of $S$ is at distance $\geq r>0$ of $x$, hence $d(x,S)\geq r>0$.

**Other idea:** (with sequences)

By contrapositive, if $d(x,S)=0$ then by definition of "inf" as greatest lower bound, we see that $\forall n\in \Bbb N,\;n\geq 1,\;\dfrac 1n$ is not a lower bound of $\{ |x-s| : s\in S\}$, so there is $s_n\in S$ s.t. $|x-s_n|<\dfrac 1n$. Thus there is a sequence $(s_n)$ of elements of $S$ converging to $x$ and $x\in\overline{S}$.