# Infimum of a sequence of distances.

Tags: metric-spaces

So I have a problem. If we consider a metric space $(M,d)$ and a subset $K$. Is it true, that for $x\in M\setminus K$ we have that $$\inf\{d(x,y):y\in K\}=\inf\{d(x,y):y\in \overline{ K}\}=\inf\left\{d(x,y):y\in \partial K\right\}?$$
I am quite confident that is not true, but I'm not sure why. Can anyone provide counterexamples or a proof for each equation? Thank you so much!

Comment: The first equality is true (see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2099527/distance-between-a-point-and-a-set-or-closure-of-it)), but the second is not : for example, if $K$ is clopen, then $\partial K = \emptyset$ so the equality cannot happen.

Comment: allright, thanks:D